# which is the best routing algorithm in networks?

Tags: algorithm, networking, routes

I have a simple question, but it may be not answered in online.

I read about use of router and router algorithm in our networks.

When i start about types routing algorithms, i just confused.

1. Distance-vector algorithm -- Ex: RIP
2. link-state algorithm -- Ex: OSPF
3. hybrid algorithm -- Ex:EIGP

And under link-state algorithm:

1. bellman-ford algorithm 2. Dijkstra's Algorithm 3.The Floyd Warshall Algorithm

According above information, which is best routing algorithm in networks?

And, is there any sub-types of algorithm used in under distance-vector algorithm?

Can anyone explain me please, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say it depend on what you need. RIP is much easier to configure than EIGRP and OSPF, but both offer more options than RIP. I work for a telecom company and I've seen static routing, RIP and BGP.

Comment: Thanks @CustomX: may i know algorithm wise?.. which algorithm is best?

Comment: isn't BellmanFord for RIP, Dijkstra for OSPF? Never heard of the FloydWarshall algorithm.

Comment: @CustomX: i m asking to get solution from you, but you asked me?.. I just confused... i think BellmanFord  and Dijkstra are types of link-state, and RIP is example of distance-vector algorithm

Comment: [BellmanFord algorithm is for distance-vector routing protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) and [Dijkstra's algorithm is for link-state routing protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)